# AngularUI DatePicker - how to parse manually entered dates?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am using an angularUI datepicker with the format attribute `datepicker-popup="MM/dd/yyyy"`

I want to make it work with both these dates:

`09/15/2015` - leading zero: this works, as it's exactly the specified format
`9/15/2015` - no leading zero - this does not get parsed.

If I change the format to `M/dd/yyyy`, the 1st one fails and the 2nd one works.

You can try for yourself directly in the [AngularUI official demo page for the datepicker](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker)

Any idea how to make it work with or without leading zeros?

FWIW: The jQueryUI (non-angular) datepicker ([official demo here](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)) doesn't seem to suffer from this.

Answer (score 0):

I had used AngularUI date-picker previously,  so you can use only one format.